# Does "adb shell input text" simulate software keyboard input?

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-keyboard

```
adb shell input text "sometext"
```

OR

```
adb shell input keyevent eventid
```

do these simulate actual input from a virtual/ hardware keyboard respectively ?

I did not find any documentation for these commands on developer.android.com/

Is there any trusted documentation for these commands?

Comment: Are there any solutions?

Comment: Yes they do. Run `adb shell input text "something really long"` while the software keyboard is open and you'll see the keys being pressed for you. (Accurate as of SDK 28 in 2020)

Answer (score 7):

`adb shell input help` produces (after a long list of input devices):

```
The commands and default sources are:
  text <string> (Default: touchscreen)
  keyevent [--longpress] <key code number or name> ... (Default: keyboard)
  tap <x> <y> (Default: touchscreen)
  swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)] (Default: touchscreen)
  press (Default: trackball)
  roll <dx> <dy> (Default: trackball)
```

So it seems "text" is indeed for virtual (Default: touchscreen) and keyevent for physical (Default: keyboard).

You can override the text input device - `adb shell input keyboard text "foo"` works just fine. You can't send raw keycodes from the screen though.

Comment: What version of android/input is this from? Older versions do not list the sources. OP's original question may not have had this option.

Comment: @cde: Android 5.0.something I believe; I've upgraded since and I can't check anymore. Regardless, treat me providing that command as "source" for info provided - "that's what the OS says, I didn't pull it out of my hat". I doubt other versions would change the mappings, even if they didn't provide them in the built-in docs.

Answer (score 5):

Related to

```
adb shell input text "some\ text"
```

I only find the source code:
E. g. for [Android 8.1 here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.1.0_r61/cmds/input/src/com/android/commands/input/Input.java).

The method  `private void sendText(int source, String text) {` is relevant for the encoding.

And searching for `KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD` that is used in previous method I found [a description here for heading "Virtual Key Character Map File"](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-character-map-files#virtual-key-character-map-file).

From that info I looked into an old SM-G900F. I found under `/system/usr/keychars/Virtual.kcm`.
Inside of that file it maps the key events to the most common characters (mostly only ASCII).

So to your question:

> do these simulate actual input from a virtual/ hardware keyboard
>   respectively ?

**Yes,** the code takes the text and tries to map it back via the KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD to key events and sends them.

In my experience all unknown characters lead to a cancellation of the whole text.
And you have to escape some characters - [sometimes space with %s, or with '\ ', other special characters like & have to be escaped too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041320/adb-shell-input-text-with-space)

And on some devices I experienced that a long text (ca. 200 characters) written with `adb shell input text "<longText>"` was partly lost - even the bigger part at the end!
It looked to me depending on the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good description available for `adb shell input *` commands, just type

```
adb shell input help
```

For `adb shell keyevent` commands, different [keycodes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) are available.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this does not answer the question. adb shell input - will give all the possible options that one can use.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a work that evaluate the performance among different keyboards and tries to simulate real-user keyboard typing. The tool that I am using (android view client) uses **input text** to send text to the device. However, when using this tool to simulate text input, I observed differences in the behaviour of the keyboards, caused by the usage of this input method.

Using **input text**, the pointer location doesn't change and the keyboard doesn't show any keypress animations. Contrariwise, when using **input tap X Y** to press a key, the visual behaviour is the same as a real user taping the key. Also, the behaviour of the GBoard is different for both input methods. When using **input text** and then tapping a suggested word, the keyboard doesn't add a trailing space. The same doesn´t happen when using **input tap**. This helps to conclude that indeed there are differences between these two input methods.

Answer (score -1):

"adb shell input keyevent eventid" for sure will not simulate real keyevent as the device id == 0.

what about "adb shell input text "sometext"" it is anyway not from pysical ... so I guess it will do is as clikcing on softkeyboard ?