# adb shell input text with space

Tags: android, shell, adb

How to send text with spaces like **"some text"** using `adb shell input text` ?

Found following solution

`adb shell input text "some%stext"` is working fine. **But any easy way to replace space with %s?**

**Example:**

```
$ adb shell input text "some text"
Error: Invalid arguments for command: text
Usage: input [<source>] <command> [<arg>...]

The sources are: 
      keyboard
      mouse
      joystick
      touchnavigation
      touchpad
      trackball
      dpad
      stylus
      gamepad
      touchscreen

The commands and default sources are:
      text <string> (Default: touchscreen)
      keyevent [--longpress] <key code number or name> ... (Default: keyboard)
      tap <x> <y> (Default: touchscreen)
      swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration(ms)] (Default: touchscreen)
      press (Default: trackball)
      roll <dx> <dy> (Default: trackball)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it with `\<space>`, like this:

```
adb shell input text "some\ text"
```

Comment: Works for me. adb 1.0.36. Android phone Pixel 2 from G.

Answer (score 8):

With gnu-linux sed (or others) installed (most linux machines come with it preinstalled) - you could use sed to replace spaces with %s.

```
adb shell input text $(echo "some text with spaces" | sed 's/ /\%s/g')
```

the %-sign has to be escaped with \.

Comment: Sed is also available in most busy box implementations found on android or added after rooting. As $()  is interpreted locally since you are using `adb shell input`, instead of inside of the android system (aka `adb shell`) you are using your system's sed. The stripped down minimal toolbox does not have sed.

Comment: the Q asks to use adb shell input, not for text manipulation inside adb shell ^^

Comment: What encoding type is this ?

What about ':' can be useful to pass URLs ?

Answer (score 2):

You can send your text like:

```
Text = "some text with spaces"
```

Replace blanks with %s

```
adb shell input text some%stext%swith%sspaces
```

Comment: This does not actually answer op's question. Op knows you need %s, they did not want to manually edit all the spaces.

Comment: @cde I of course assumed that a string replace function would be used to change blanks to %s

Answer (score 1):

adb shell "input text 'some text'"

Answer (score 0):

The best way replaces special characters with .

```
 val message = text.replace("|", "\\|")
            .replace("\"", "\\\"")
            .replace("\'", "\\\'")
            .replace("<", "\\<")
            .replace(">", "\\>")
            .replace(";", "\\;")
            .replace("?", "\\?")
            .replace("`", "\\`")
            .replace("&", "\\&")
            .replace("*", "\\*")
            .replace("(", "\\(")
            .replace(")", "\\)")
            .replace("~", "\\~")
            .replace(" ", "\\ ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the text in single quote:

```
adb shell input text 'some text'
```