# Can I remotely access web browser tabs in my Oculus Quest/Oculus Go from a program running on my computer?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, oculus, oculusgo

Currently the [Oculus Quest](https://www.oculus.com/quest/) headset's browser seems pretty basic, and doesn't have features such as copy/paste, etc. It also doesn't seem like it can't handle launching other apps via 'deep links'. I don't personally have an Oculus Go, but I assume it would be a pretty similar experience?

Is there any way we can access the URL's/history/etc in the headset's browser from a computer (eg. programatically)? At least that way we could copy the relevant parts, and maybe [programatically 'type' them back into the headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386237/is-it-possible-to-copy-paste-type-eg-a-password-from-an-app-into-the-oculus-q) in the area we need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It [seems this is possible](https://github.com/the-expanse/SideQuest/issues/34#issuecomment-497794598) using [Chrome DevTools Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?hl=en) if you have [developer mode](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/quest/latest/concepts/mobile-device-setup-quest/) enabled on your headset.

You can find the [official documentation on the Oculus developer website](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/oculus-browser/latest/concepts/browser-remote-debugging/#starting-a-remote-debugging-session-with-chrome-developer-tools).

Once [developer mode is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386237/is-it-possible-to-copy-paste-type-eg-a-password-from-an-app-into-the-oculus-q/56386580#56386580), plug your headset into your computer with the USB-C cable.

While the headset is connected to your computer:

- Open Google Chrome on the computer
- Access the special `chrome://inspect/#devices` URL
- Locate the headset under the 'Remote Target' heading
- Click 'inspect' on the page you want to interact with

There seems to be an 'inspect' option for each 'tab' open within the headset web browser:

[image: Chrome DevTools 'inspect' open tabs]

From there, you have access to the browser window like you normally would with DevTools, so can access things from the JavaScript console like the URL, or to manipulate fields:
[image: Chrome DevTools JavaScript console]

As far as doing this programatically, the [DevTools protocol is documented](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/), and there are many [SDK's for it in various languages](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/awesome-chrome-devtools#protocol-driver-libraries).

The DevTools protocol docs talk about the [DOM Domain](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM) (among other things), which seems to give similar features as the above 'inspect' functionality. By using [`DOM.getDocument`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM#method-getDocument) you can get the equivalent of accessing `document` from the Chrome DevTools console. This returns a [Node object](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM#type-Node) which contains values such as `documentURL`.